# How to get values of multiple append textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox that can be append.. and i want to get the values of each textbox

```js
$('#entryData').append('<div><input type="text" id="quantity"></div>');
var total = $('#quantity').val();
console.log(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="entryData">
  <input type="text" id="quantity">
  <input type="button" value="+">
  <input type="button" value="Total">
</div>
```

but I am only getting the first textbox value and not the other textbox

Comment: Use `class` instead of `id` and iterate.

Comment: what is `#entryData`??

Comment: Post your full code.

Comment: still not working for me..

Comment: i've edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='entryData' >
 <input type="text" class='quantity'>
 <input type="button" value="+" id='add'>
 <input type="button" value="Total" id='total'>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#add').click(function(){
 $('#entryData').append('<div><input type="text" class="quantity"></div>');
});
$('#total').click(function(){
var total=0;
 $('.quantity').each(function(index,quantity){
   total=total+parseInt($(this).val());
 });
   alert(total);
});

});

</script>
```

I expect this is what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Or make it like this:

```
<div id='entryData' >
 <input type="number" class='quantity'>
 <input type="button" value="+" id='add'>
 <input type="button" value="Total" id='total'>
</div>
```

If you expect numbers - make the field number.

```
//this should come from helper method file/lib - for reusability
const sum = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
const mapToInt = (idx,element) => { if (element.value !== "") { return parseInt(element.value, 10); } }

$(document).ready(() =>{

    $('#add').click( () => {
        $('#entryData').append('<div><input type="number" class="quantity" /></div>');
    });

    $('#total').click( () => {
        let total = $(".quantity").map(mapToInt).get().reduce(sum);
        console.log ( total );
    });
});
```

**Edit**: sum (aggregation func) and mapToInt can be reused if you consider having more functional approach.